# Argument of \@iirsbox has an extra }

Tags: listings

I am trying to do this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
     frame=single,
     breaklines=true,
     postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]
 }
 \begin{document}
 \section{Gramática Tradutora}
 \lstinputlisting{stock.y}
 \end{document}
```

My `stock.y` file starts like this:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include "stock.h"
/* Declaracoes C diversas */
int fatura = 0;
float total_fatura;
float total_vendas = 0;
%}
```

And i am getting this error in latex:

```
! Argument of \@iirsbox has an extra }.
```

\par 
l.1 %{

I don't know how to solve this. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a minimal working document, i.e. the version that has those errors, not just fragments

Comment: What is the wrong `\raisebox{0ex}[0pt][0pt]` supposed to do? Remove the line in `\lstset` containing it. *Et voilà*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
 postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]
```

makes no sense. Remove it.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
     frame=single,
     breaklines=true,
}

\begin{document}

\section{Gramática Tradutora}

\lstinputlisting{stock.y}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solved the problem, but can you explain why it was causing that error? Grateful

Comment: @P_Ferreira With `postbreak=x` you are saying that after a line break `listings` should print `x`; in your case it was `\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]`, which lacks the object to be raised.